# C++ Star Pattern Pyramid

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the following pattern:

```
*
* *
* * *
* *
*
```

.. but I can't figure it out.

This is the logic that I am following.

1. i variable is for the row number.
2. j variable is for the column number.
3. Using for loops to guide the row number and column number.

I am able to create an increasing triangle pattern using the above logic but can't figure out how to start decreasing the pattern to form a pyramid.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (i; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            for (j; j <= 0; j--)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd really appreciate some guidance to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for (i; i <= 6; i++)
> ```

It has no effect to mention a variable (`i`) in the `init-statement` of a for loop if there is wheter a declaration nor an assignment.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int width = 8;

    // raising flank:
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; ++k) {
            std::cout << "* ";
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }

    // falling flank:
    for (int i = width - 1; i; --i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
            std::cout << "* ";
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

Comment: Traditionally, the `for` statement would be `for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)`.  Just stating for the record.  Maybe easier for beginners to understand.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Changed.

Comment: @Swordfish I suggest to include braces for inner `for` loops, it makes intent clearer, and debugging too.